# Why is grid row height auto not following content?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So I want to achieve the following layout i drafted in word:

[image]

and so I decided to go with a grid structure, with just four rows but each will have a different row height depending on the content.

I researched that using **auto** for the row height would allow it to **follow the content's height** however it doesn't seem to be working for me.

[image]

As you can see, there seem to be a gap produced in each row. Isn't it supposed to follow the content's height which is the end of the textarea/textbox bottom? Why is it producing the gaps after the textbox? How do i make sure each row in the grid follows the height of the content?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

#output2 {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: grid;
    /*auto height for each row set here */
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
}

#address_final {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#address_disp {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}

#address {
    min-height: 20vh;
}

#name_country, #iden_passport {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
}

#name_final, #country_final, #identity_final, #passport_final {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
}

#name, #country, #identity, #passport {
    min-height: 10vh;
}

#map_panel {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:#95959521;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "output2">
    <div id = "address_final">
        <div id = "address_disp">
            Address
            <textarea id = "address" disabled></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "name_country">
        <div id = "name_final">
            Name
            <input type="text" id = "name" disabled>
        </div>
        <div id = "country_final">
            Country
            <input type="text" id = "country" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "iden_passport">
        <div id = "identity_final">
            IdentityNumber
            <input type="text" id = "identity" disabled>
        </div>
        <div id = "passport_final">
            PassportNo
            <input type="text" id = "passport" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "map_panel">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Modify `#output2` height to "auto" and set all child divs height to "fit-content"

Comment: @Adam P. I need #output2 height to be fixed at 90vh. Is there no other way?

Comment: If you want a grid layout, then why use so many flexboxes as children? Btw if you want to use auto height for all rows you can simply use: `grid-auto-rows: auto;`it will add as many rows as needed with the height of auto. why using flexboxes for the columns instead of letting grid take control of it?

Comment: `height: auto;` for `grid cards` will not adept to the height needed if the grid has a delcared `min` or `fixed width`. In that case it will contribute the elftover space equaly to fill the grids height. For that you have `min-content`